# Menu Component CakePHP markstory

Tags: php, cakephp, components, acl, cakephp-2.2

I've edited the CakePHP Menu Component made by Mark Story to make it compatible with CakePHP 2.2.3.
https://github.com/markstory/cakephp_menu_component

The problem is that I still get an error that I can't figure out how to get rid of:

http://imm.io/MK9J

http://imm.io/MK9W

http://imm.io/MKa7

Here is the modified code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Menu Component
 *
 * Uses ACL to generate Menus.
 *
 * Copyright 2008, Mark Story.
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright Copyright 2008, Mark Story.
 * @link http://mark-story.com
 * @version 1.1
 * @author Mark Story <mark@mark-story.com>
 * @license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php The MIT License
 */
class MenuComponent extends Component {
/**
 * The Default Menu Parent for things that have no parent element defined
 * used a lot by menu items generated by controller folder scrapings
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $defaultMenuParent = null;
/**
 * Set to false to disable the auto menu generation in startup()
 * Useful if you want your menus generated off of Aro's other than the user in the current session.
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
    public $autoLoad = true;
/**
 * Controller reference
 *
 * @var object
 */ 
    public $Controller = null;
/**
 * Components used by Menu
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Acl', 'Auth');

/**
 * Key for the caching
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $cacheKey = 'menu_storage';

/**
 * Time to cache menus for.
 *
 * @var string  String compatible with strtotime.
 */
    public $cacheTime = '+1 day';
/**
 * cache config key
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $cacheConfig = 'menu_component';
/**
 * Separator between controller and action name.
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $aclSeparator = '/';

/**
 * The Node path to get to the controller listing
 *
 * @var string
 **/
    public $aclPath = 'controllers/';

/**
 * Array of Actions to exclude when making menus.
 * Per controller exclusions can be set with Controller::menuOptions
 *
 * @var array
 **/
    public $excludeActions = array('view', 'edit', 'delete', 'admin_edit', 'admin_delete', 'admin_edit', 'admin_view');

/**
 * Completed list of methods to not include in menus. Includes all of Controller's methods.
 *
 * @var array
 **/
    public $excludedMethods = array();
/**
 * The Completed menu for the current user.
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $menu = array(); 

/**
 * Raw menus before formatting, either loaded from parsing controllers directory or loading Cache
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $rawMenus = array();
/**
 * Internal Flag to check if new menus have been added to a cached menu set.  Indicates that new menu items
 * have been added and that menus need to be rebuilt.
 * 
 */
    protected $_rebuildMenus = false;

/**
 * initialize function
 *
 * Takes Settings declared in Controller and assigns them.
 *
 * @return bool
 **/
    public function initialize(Controller $controller) {
        if (!empty($settings)) {
            $this->_set($settings);
        }
        return true;
    }

/**
 * Startup Method
 *
 * Automatically makes menus for all a the controllers based on the current user.
 * If $this->autoLoad = false then you must manually loadCache(), 
 * contstructMenu() and writeCache().
 *
 * @param Object $Controller
 */
    public function startup(Controller $controller) {
        $this->Controller =& $Controller;

        Cache::config($this->cacheConfig, array('engine' => 'File', 'duration' => $this->cacheTime, 'prefix' => $this->cacheKey));

        //no active session, no menu can be generated
        if (!$this->Auth->user()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->autoLoad) {
            $this->loadCache();
            $this->constructMenu($this->Auth->user());
            $this->writeCache();
        }
    }

/**
 * Write the current Block Access data to a file.
 *
 * @return boolean on success of writing a file.
 */
    public function writeCache() {
        $data = array(
            'menus' => $this->rawMenus
        );
        if (Cache::write($this->cacheKey, $data, $this->cacheConfig)) {
            return true;
        }
        $this->log('Menu Component - Could not write Menu cache.');
        return false;
    }

/**
 * Load the Cached Permissions and restore them
 *
 * @return boolean true if cache was loaded.
 */
    public function loadCache() {
        if ($data = Cache::read($this->cacheKey, $this->cacheConfig)) {
            $this->rawMenus = $this->_mergeMenuCache($data['menus']);
            return true;
        }
        $this->_rebuildMenus = true;
        return false;
    }

/**
 * Clears the raw Menu Cache, this will in turn force
 * a menu rebuild for each ARO that needs a menu.
 *
 * @return boolean
 **/
    public function clearCache() {
        return Cache::delete($this->cacheKey, $this->cacheConfig);
    }

/**
 * Construct the menus From the Controllers in the Application.  This is an expensive
 * Process Timewise and is cached.
 *
 * @param string $aro  Aro Alias / identification array that a menu is needed for.
 */ 
    public function constructMenu($aro) {
        $aroKey = $aro;
        if (is_array($aro)) {
            $aroKey = key($aro) . $aro[key($aro)];
        }
        $cacheKey = $aroKey . '_' . $this->cacheKey;
        $completeMenu = Cache::read($cacheKey, $this->cacheConfig);
        if (!$completeMenu || $this->_rebuildMenus == true) {
            $this->generateRawMenus();

            $menu = array();
            $size = count($this->rawMenus);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
                $item = $this->rawMenus[$i];

                $aco = Inflector::underscore($item['url']['controller']);
                if (isset($item['url']['action'])) {
                    $aco = $this->aclPath . $aco . $this->aclSeparator . $item['url']['action'];
                }
                if ($this->Acl->check($aco, $aro)) {
                    if (!isset($menu[$item['id']])) {
                        $menu[$item['id']] = $this->rawMenus[$i];
                    }
                }
            }
            $completeMenu = $this->_formatMenu($menu);
            Cache::write($cacheKey, $completeMenu, $this->cacheConfig);
        }
        $this->menu = $completeMenu;
    }

/**
 * Generate Raw Menus from Controller in the Application
 * Loads a list of All controllers in the app/controllers, imports the class and gets a method
 * list.  Uses a common exclusion list to remove unwanted methods.  Each Controller can specify a 
 * menuOptions var which allows additional menu configuration.
 * 
 * Menu Options for Controllers:
 *      exclude => actions to exclude from the menu list
 *      parent => Parent link to add a controller / actions underneath
 *      alias => array of action => aliases Allows you to set friendly link names for actions
 *
 * @return void sets $this->rawMenus
 */ 
    public function generateRawMenus() {
        $Controllers = $this->getControllers();
        $cakeAdmin = Configure::read('Routing.admin');
        $this->createExclusions();

        //go through the controllers folder and make an array of every menu that could be used.
        foreach($Controllers as $Controller) {
            if ($Controller == 'App') {
                continue;
            }

            $ctrlName = $Controller;
            App::uses($ctrlName, 'Controller');
            $ctrlclass = $ctrlName;
            $methods = get_class_methods($ctrlclass);
            $classVars = get_class_vars($ctrlclass);

            $menuOptions = $this->setOptions($classVars);
            if ($menuOptions === false) {
                continue;
            }

            $methods = $this->filterMethods($methods, $menuOptions['exclude']);

            $ctrlCamel = Inflector::variable($ctrlName);
            $ctrlHuman = Inflector::humanize(Inflector::underscore($ctrlCamel));
            $methodList = array();
            $adminController = false;
            foreach ($methods as $action) {
                $camelAction = Inflector::variable($action);

                if (empty($menuOptions['alias']) || !isset($menuOptions['alias'][$action])) {
                    $human = Inflector::humanize(Inflector::underscore($action));
                } else {
                    $human = $menuOptions['alias'][$action];
                }
                $url = array(
                    'controller' => $ctrlCamel,
                    'action' => $action
                );
                if ($cakeAdmin) {
                    $url[$cakeAdmin] = false;
                }
                if (strpos($action, $cakeAdmin . '_') !== false && $cakeAdmin) {
                    $url[$cakeAdmin] = true;
                    $adminController = true;
                }

                $parent = $menuOptions['controllerButton'] ? $ctrlCamel : $menuOptions['parent'];
                $this->rawMenus[] = array(
                    'parent' => $parent,
                    'id' => $this->_createId($ctrlCamel, $action),
                    'title' => $human,
                    'url' => $url,
                    'weight' => 0,
                );
            }

            if ($menuOptions['controllerButton']) {
                //If an admin index exists use it.
                $action = $adminController ? $cakeAdmin . '_index' : 'index';
                $url = array(
                    'controller' => $ctrlCamel,
                    'action' => $action,
                    'admin' => $adminController,
                );
                $menuItem = array(
                    'parent' => $menuOptions['parent'],
                    'id' => $ctrlCamel,
                    'title' => $ctrlHuman,
                    'url' => $url,
                    'weight' => 0
                );
                $this->rawMenus[] = $menuItem;
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * Get the Controllers in the Application
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
    public function getControllers() {
        return App::objects('controller');
    }

/**
 * filter out methods based on $menuOptions.
 * Removes private actions as well.
 *
 * @param array $methods  Array of methods to prepare
 * @param array $remove Array of additional Methods to remove, normally options on the controller.
 * @return array
 **/
    public function filterMethods($methods, $remove = array()) {
        if (!empty($remove)) {
            $remove = array_map('strtolower', $remove);
        }
        $exclusions = array_merge($this->excludedMethods, $remove);
        foreach ($methods as $k => $method) {
            $method = strtolower($method);
            if (strpos($method, '_', 0) === 0) {
                unset($methods[$k]);
            }
            if (in_array($method, $exclusions)) {
                unset($methods[$k]);
            }
        }
        return array_values($methods);
    }

/**
 * Set the Options for the current Controller.
 *
 * @return mixed.  Array of options or false on total exclusion
 **/
    public function setOptions($controllerVars) {
        $cakeAdmin = Configure::read('Routing.admin');
        $menuOptions = isset($controllerVars['menuOptions']) ? $controllerVars['menuOptions'] : array();

        $exclude = array('view', 'edit', 'delete', $cakeAdmin . '_edit', 
            $cakeAdmin . '_delete', $cakeAdmin . '_edit', $cakeAdmin . '_view');

        $defaults = array(
            'exclude' => $exclude, 
            'alias' => array(), 
            'parent' => $this->defaultMenuParent, 
            'controllerButton' => true
        );
        $menuOptions = Set::merge($defaults, $menuOptions);
        if (in_array('*', (array)$menuOptions['exclude'])) {
            return false;
        }
        return $menuOptions;
    }

/**
 * Creates the Exclusions for generating menus.
 *
 * @return void
 **/
    public function createExclusions() {
        $methods = array_merge(get_class_methods('Controller'), $this->excludeActions);
        $this->excludedMethods = array_map('strtolower', $methods);
    }
/**
 * Add a Menu Item.
 * Allows manual Insertion into the menu system.
 * If Added after constructMenu()  It will not be shown
 *
 * @param string $parent
 * @param array $menu
 *      'Menu' Array
 *          'title' => name
 *          'url' => url array of menu, url strings are lame and won't work
 *          'key' => unique name of this menu for parenting purposes.
 *          'controller' => controller Name this action is from
 */
    public function addMenu($menu) {
        $defaults = array(
            'title' => null,
            'url' => null,
            'parent' => null,
            'id' => null,
            'weight' => 0,
        );
        $menu = array_merge($defaults, $menu);
        if (!$menu['id'] && isset($menu['url'])) {
            $menu['id'] = $this->_createId($menu['url']);
        }
        if (!$menu['title'] && isset($menu['url']['action'])) {
            $menu['title'] = Inflector::humanize($menu['url']['action']);
        }
        $this->rawMenus[] = $menu;
    }

/**
 * BeforeRender Callback.
 *
 */
    public function beforeRender(Controller $controller) {
        $this->Controller->set('menu', $this->menu);
    }

/**
 * Make a Unique Menu item key
 *
 * @param array $parts
 * @return string Unique key name
 */
    protected function _createId() {
        $parts = func_get_args();
        if (is_array($parts[0])) {
            $parts = $parts[0];
        }
        $key = Inflector::variable(implode('-', $parts));
        return $key;
    }

/**
 * Recursive function to construct Menu
 *
 * @param unknown_type $menu
 * @param unknown_type $parentId
 */
    protected function _formatMenu($menu) {
        $out = $idMap = array();
        foreach ($menu as $item) {
            $item['children'] = array();
            $id = $item['id'];
            $parentId = $item['parent'];
            if (isset($idMap[$id]['children'])) {
                $idMap[$id] = am($item, $idMap[$id]);
            } else {
                $idMap[$id] = am($item, array('children' => array()));
            }
            if ($parentId) {
                $idMap[$parentId]['children'][] =& $idMap[$id];
            } else {
                $out[] =& $idMap[$id];
            }
        }
        usort($out, array(&$this, '_sortMenu'));
        return $out;
    }

/**
 * Sort the menu before returning it. Used with usort()
 *
 * @return int
 **/
    protected function _sortMenu($one, $two) {
        if ($one['weight'] == $two['weight']) {
            return 1;
        }
        return ($one['weight'] < $two['weight']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
/**
 * Merge the Cached menus with the Menus added in Controller::beforeFilter to ensure they are unique.
 *
 * @param array $cachedMenus
 * @return array Merged Menus
 */
    protected function _mergeMenuCache($cachedMenus) {
        $cacheCount = sizeOf($cachedMenus);
        $currentCount = sizeOf($this->rawMenus);
        $tmp = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $currentCount; $i++) {
            $exist = false;
            $addedMenu = $this->rawMenus[$i];
            for ($j =0; $j < $cacheCount; $j++) {
                $cachedItem = $cachedMenus[$j];
                if ($addedMenu['id'] == $cachedItem['id']) {
                    $exist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($exist) {
                continue;
            }
            $tmp[] = $addedMenu;
        }
        if (!empty($tmp)) {
            $this->_rebuildMenus = true;
        }
        return array_merge($cachedMenus, $tmp);
    }

}
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have time to try and test everything right now, I can tell you two things, first is that you've got the argument order wrong in the [`AclComponent::check`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html#checking-permissions-the-acl-component) call (`MenuComponent`, line 217), the first argument should be the `ARO`, and the second one should be the `ACO`.

The other problem is that the data you are passing to `MenuComponent::constructMenu` (and consequently to `AclComponent::check`) is in the wrong format, it should be an array where the first item is indexed by a string (the model name) holding the `ARO` data, ie something like this:

```
array
(
    'User' => array
    (
        'id' => '33',
        'username' => 'user',
        'email' => 'user@user.com',
        ...
    )
)
```

This is neccessary because the key is being used by the menu component for caching, as well as by the `AclNode` model for accessing the `ARO` data. The way you are passing the data it will fetch `id` as the key, and try to access the data of this key as an array, which will fail because the value indexed by `id` holds a string (`33`), thus the `illegal string offset` error.

So the call to `MenuComponent::constructMenu` should effectively look something like this, where `User` should be the name of your user model:

```
$this->constructMenu(array('User' => $this->Auth->user()));
```

**However the model name shouldn't be hardcoded**, you should try retreiving it from the `Auth` component! For example like this (not tested!):

```
$this->Auth->authenticate[key($this->Auth->authenticate)]['userModel']
```